# Faster sort option in sas?

Tags: sorting, sas

I have a large dataset of 1.2crore rows, which is taking around 30 min in **sorting** using usual **SAS proc sort**. Is there any faster algorithm/option in **sas**?
Kuber

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without more details on how you are using the sorted dataset and what fields and lengths make up your dataset here's a few things you can try:

- Use the `tagsort` option in proc sort.  This is useful when the dataset is wide.
- Create an index instead of sorting.  If you are just going to do some by group processing then this will be faster and will work just as well.
- If you are sorting in order to do a merge consider using either SQL joins (which may not need to sort as much data) or hashtables (which can be used to merge and don't require sorted data).
- Compress the output dataset (if you aren't already) and/or the input dataset.  This will reduce the IO.

But to answer your question, there is no faster sort procedure in sas then `proc sort`.  According to the below PDF: *The SAS® sort routine is of order O(NlogN), which is as
fast as a comparison sort can be.*

If you are working at a site that has syncsort licensed then this can speed it up, but this is usually enabled by default.

http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi26/p121-26.pdf

Comment: Hi Rob, PROC SQL does sort internally, except when doing an inner join and one of the 2 tables being joined to is small enough to fit into memroy - in which case it uses a hash join (hence no sorting being done) or when using index join. Add "_METHOD" as an PROC SQL option and see if its sorting data in the background or not. http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/forum2008/097-2008.pdf

Comment: Good point.  I'm guessing you could get away with having the `from` table being unsorted and only the table being joined to needing to be sorted.  So it may depend on the situation? Either way I've updated my answer to reflect your comment.

Answer (score 0):

If the reason you need to sort your data set is to merge it with another data set, you might look at doing your merge/lookup using a [HASH](http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi30/236-30.pdf) object. Then you might not need to sort it.